# How to maintain VaR at 5% and max return in Portfolio Analytics

Tags: portfolio-optimization, performanceanalytics

For Asset Allocation in R using Portfolio Analytics, is there a way to set risk as constant number, then optimize portfolio returns? For example, to maintain VaR always at 5% (conservative), how do weights of 8 assets change in portfolio to max return? In contrast, how do the weights change compared to a risky (VaR =20%) portfolio? In the Portfolio Analytics package, we can only set min risk as objective, but not set risk as a constant number. (Different from Equal Risk Contribution)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ‘**portfolio.optimization**' Package with this you can optimize your portfolio  with a VaR set at 5% Max target and try to find the right allocation by using the function :

> optimal.portfolio.expected.shortfall

or you can optimize by CVaR:

> optimal.portfolio.expected.shortfall.long.short

... this is quite straight forward!!